# Do I have to call Release() method on CComPtr objects?

Tags: windows, com, atl, smart-pointers, sapi

I'm working with SAPI5 API for processing text to speech. If I simplify my code looks like this (I removed error checking to simplify it as much as possible):

```
int main() {
    CoInitialize(NULL);
    CComPtr<ISpVoice> spVoice;
    spVoice.CoCreateInstance(CLSID_SpVoice);
    ...
    CoUninitialize();
    return 0;
}
```

For some weird reason my code crashes if I don't call spVoice.Release(). So the code above crashes, but this code works nicely:

```
int main() {
    CoInitialize(NULL);
    CComPtr<ISpVoice> spVoice;
    spVoice.CoCreateInstance(CLSID_SpVoice);
    ...
    spVoice.Release();
    CoUninitialize();
    return 0;
}
```

Doesn't `CComPtr` release the underlying object automatically as it goes out of scope?

I looked at the implementation of `CComPtr` and it does call `Release` in the destructor itself.

So I'm wondering what could have gone wrong and why is it that if I call `Release` myself, my code doesn't crash. But if I don't call `Release` then it crashes.

Comment: Generally a pointer that isn't released doesn't crash, it just creates a memory leak. Does the snippet you've created act the same as your full program?

Comment: @MarkRansom I narrowed the crash down to invoking `spVoice.Release()`. I can try creating a working snippet and keep adding things until it crashes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

CComPtr's destructor will call Release.  However, it does that when the object falls out of scope.  In your above code, this is just before main returns, which is *after* the call to CoUninitialize.

The following code is more correct, and guarantees the destructor runs prior to CoUninitialize.

```
int main() {
    CoInitialize(NULL);
    { // Begin scope
        CComPtr<ISpVoice> spVoice;
        spVoice.CoCreateInstance(CLSID_SpVoice);
        ...
    } / End scope, spVoice's destructor runs.
    CoUninitialize();
    return 0;
}
```

An alternative is to create an RAII wrapper around CoInitialize/CoUninitialize.  If this new object is declared prior to spVoice, it's destructor will run after spVoice's destructor, guaranteeing correct order.

Comment: I used the RAII wrapper around CoInitialize/CoUninitialize and it doesn't crash anymore. Thanks everyone who helped me!

Comment: why _If you call Release() after ::CoUninitialize()_ it causes the crash?

Answer (score -1):

You are right, you must NOT invoke Release. This is done automatically in the destructor.
One reason of the crash might be a side effect that takes place because you don't initialize the COM appartment at the begin of your program.

Comment: The object is released in the destructor, but [you need to know when your destructors run](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/05/20/135841.aspx).

Comment: @mox, I'm sorry, I actually do initialize COM. I forgot to mention this in the code snippet as I wanted to have it as short as possible.

Comment: @RaymondChen Thanks for linking to the article. I'll read it now.

Comment: @RaymondChen That must be it! I've exactly the same structure that you show in your `CoUninitialize` example. I'm now refactoring code to make sure `spVoice` gets destroyed before `CoUninitialize` gets called. (PS. I also updated my code example in the question.)